# Perform operations on std::variant<POD_PTR*...> in a generic way

Tags: c++, pointers, variant

Say the following `variant` is given:
`using Variant = std::variant<uint32_t*, uint16_t*>`

And then, a `vector` of such `variant`s is needed:
`using VariantVecType = std::vector<Variant>`

How would one go about accessing the underlying values (pointed to by those pointers) to perform arithmetic operations on them in a more generic way (i.e. without using `std::get_if`) e.g.

```
   uint32_t i0 = 1;
   uint16_t i1 = 2;

   Variant v0{ &i0 };
   Variant v1{ &i1 };

   VariantVecType vec{v0, v1};

   for(auto& v : vec)
        if(auto pval = std::get_if<uint32_t*>(&v))
            std::cout << "Underlying int value: " << *(*pval) << '\n';  
        else if(auto pval = std::get_if<uint16_t*>(&v))
            std::cout << "Underlying int value: " << *(*pval) << '\n';  
        else
            std::cout << "failed to get value!" << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

// from cppref:
// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
 

int main() {
    uint32_t i0 = 1;
    uint16_t i1 = 2;

    using Variant = std::variant<uint32_t*, uint16_t*>;
    Variant v0{ &i0 };
    Variant v1{ &i1 };

    using VariantVecType = std::vector<Variant>;
    VariantVecType vec{v0, v1};

   for(auto& v : vec) {
       std::visit(overloaded {
            [](uint32_t* arg) { std::cout << "Underlying uint32 value: " << *arg << '\n'; },
            [](uint16_t* arg) { std::cout << "Underlying uint16 value: " << *arg << '\n'; },
       }, v);
   }
}
```

But a `std::variant<uint32_t*, uint16_t*>` seems a bit awkward. pointers in 64-bit machines are bigger then both types. And accessing the elements requires indirection=slow. Plus the arithmetic on both types will be about the same **(except for overflow)**. So why not have a normal `std::vector<uint32_t>`?

Comment: That's a good observation! Rationale behind this is to keep arrays of addresses to specific fields in a HW register (modeled as a struct) in order to allow for easy iteration over them. Hope that makes sense! And if it does, can you think of another way of doing it?